# Selecting the correct starting point for an offset sum

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel sheet where I am trying to sum the 4 quarters (so 1 year) after a select starting point quarter.  A column in the sheet determines the specific starting point, Q1\2009 for example.  The starting point changes for every row. 
 There are then header columns for each quarter in a range of years with values under each column for that quarter.  I know the end will be the formula

```
=SUM(OFFSET("cell I want",0,0,1,4))
```

but I don't know how to pick that inside one.  I've been able to display the cell address with:

`=CELL("address",INDEX(I11:AP11,MATCH(E11,$I$1:$AO$1,0)))`

But I can't just slip that into my offset because it outputs text, and not an actual address, and the offset function doesn't read text there.

Can someone help me with this?  Thanks.

Comment: Make that `=CELL()` as a named range, and use that name in your `OFFSET`.  You may need to use with `INDIRECT` too.

Comment: INDEX formula by itself returns a valid range reference. I'd try **=SUM(OFFSET(INDEX(I11:AP11,MATCH(E11,$I$1:$AO$1,0)),0,0,1,4))**

Comment: `INDEX(I11:AP11,MATCH(E11,$I$1:$AO$1,0))` makes no sense to me. Please provide a [mcve] with sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index returns a range, so you can use Index/Match to determine the starting cell.

```
=SUM(OFFSET(INDEX(I11:AP11,MATCH(E11,$I$1:$AO$1,0)),0,0,1,4)‌​)
```

Comment: I tried this at first, and I got an error, then I just deleted the last parenthesis and typed it again, boom!  working perfectly.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Please take the time to mark the answer as described in the [Tour]. That is how you can say Thanks around here.